# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Failed to start browser

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I use the same code and also version on 2 computers, but another cannot start Firefox. Please help me

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Failed to start browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe: permission denied (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>
> Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
>
> Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
>         System info: host: 'XUANTRUONG-PC', ip: '192.168.1.95', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
>         Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

Comment: Which version of Selenium, Gecko driver & Firefox are you using?

Comment: sele 3.3.1, gecko v0.15, firefox v 53(64 bit). I dont know why 2 enviroments and the same code but only one got this error.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: http://www.guru99.com/first-webdriver-script.html

Comment: the first code on that site

Comment: Check my Answer and update me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To work with Selenium 3.4.0 you need to mandatory download gecko driver v0.16.0 (or above) from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and save it in your machine. Upgrade your Mozila Firefox to the latest stable version (v 53.x). Use the absolute path of the geckodriver in your code while `System.setProperty`

In your code:

Replace `System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\geckodriver.exe");`

with
`System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");`

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: i know that System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe"); i can run well but the driver can not start the firefox

Comment: @JoePhan Disable the extensions​ if any on the system it doesn't starts & execute again.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Failed to start browser \\?\C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe: permission denied
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'XUANTRUONG-PC', ip: '192.168.1.95', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver \n

New error after i did everything you said. could i contact you via skype pleased? @Dev

Comment: Do you have TeamViewer v12 installed on your PC?

Comment: of course, share me your skype and we get more information.